# Connect to an existing interactive AWS Glue session

Tags: aws-glue

I am using an AWS Glue interactive notebook to parse a very large JSON file from S3 using PySpark. I created a notebook, kicked off the session, and began reading in my file. While loading, my AWS console session expired and when I reloaded the tab I was no longer connected to my session.

If I start a new interactive session and run `%list_sessions`, I can see the id of my previous session. How do I reconnect to this session in my notebook to pick up where I left off?

Comment: are you using zeppelin or jupyter?

Comment: jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I had to search through my browser history for the link and that worked for me.

[web browser history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMNjU.png)

I can't find an obvious solution, but that worked for me.

** note all scripts and code will be gone when you reconnect.